# String Manupulation using DB2

Tags: sql, string, db2, logic, case

I have a table with current preferred Customer services, and I want to create and engine to push for the Next Possible Best Offer.

My table looks like this:

| Customer ID | PREFERRED_SERVICE |
| --- | --- |
| aaaa | P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET |
| bbbb | P2P_TRANSFER_OFFNET,BILL_PAY |
| cccc | P2P_TRANSFER_OFFNET |
| dddd | MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET |
| eeee | MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET,P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET |
| ffff | BILL_PAY |
| gggg | P2P_TRANSFER_OFFNET,BILL_PAY |
| hhhh | MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET,P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET, GOVT_PAY |

```
select 
distinct customer_id,
CASE
   WHEN  UPPER(PREFERRED_SERVICE) LIKE '%P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET%' THEN 'BILL_PAY/MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET'
   WHEN  UPPER(PREFERRED_SERVICE) LIKE '%MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET%' THEN 'P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET/BILL_PAY'
   WHEN  UPPER(PREFERRED_SERVICE) LIKE '%MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET,P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET%' THEN 'PAY BILL'
   ELSE 'PAY BILL/P2P AM/MERCHPAY_AM'
END NEXT_BEST_OFFER
from Table_name_a
```

The desired Output is something like:

| Customer ID | PREFERRED_SERVICE | NEXT_BEST_OFFER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaaa | P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET | BILL_PAY/MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET |
| bbbb | P2P_TRANSFER_OFFNET,BILL_PAY | P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET/MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET |
| cccc | P2P_TRANSFER_OFFNET | P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET/MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET/BILL_PAY |
| dddd | MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET | P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET/BILL_PAY |
| eeee | MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET,P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET | BILL_PAY |
| ffff | BILL_PAY | P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET/MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET |
| gggg | P2P_TRANSFER_OFFNET,BILL_PAY | P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET/MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET |
| hhhh | MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET,P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET, GOVT_PAY | BILL_PAY |

--- The aim is to have a script smart enough to understand that:

1. `WHEN  UPPER(PREFERRED_SERVICE) LIKE '%P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET%' THEN 'BILL_PAY/MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET'` > I meant the column string contain 'P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET' only
2. `WHEN  UPPER(PREFERRED_SERVICE) LIKE '%MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET%' THEN 'P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET/BILL_PAY'` > I meant the column string contain 'MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET' only
3. `WHEN  UPPER(PREFERRED_SERVICE) LIKE '%MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET,P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET%' THEN 'BILL_PAY'` > I meant the string in a column contain words 'MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET,P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET%' in any order, then I want to push 'BILL PAY'

Also:

4. when there is 'P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET, + Any product that is not Merchant Pay Onnet' > Push 'Merch Pay Onnet + Bill Pay'
5. when there is 'Merch Pay On net, + Any product That is not P2P transfer Onnet' > Push 'P2P transfer Onnet + Bill Pay'

Comment: You use ``,`` and ``\`` as delimiter between service names. What is difference?

Comment: There is no significant difference, the table that has data uses (,), the preferred column uses (/)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem in the usual way

```
   case when ...  
        when
   else ...
```

This is difficult to understand and support.
I will propose a different approach based on service priorities.

1. Create Service table, if not exist?, and set priority for service - preferred service 1, 2 - next preferred

```
create table service (id int,Service_Name varchar(20),priority int);
insert into service values
 (1,'BILL_PAY'           ,1)
,(2,'GOVT_PAY'           ,3)
,(3,'MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET' ,1)
,(4,'P2P_TRANSFER_OFFNET',2)
,(5,'P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET' ,1)
;
```

2.CTE1: Join Customer services table with Services for select services, **not included** to  PREFERRED_SERVICE and take min priority for them.

3. Take services with min priority, aggregate by LISTAGG.

```
with cte1 as (select *
  ,min(priority)over(partition by customer_id) minNext_offer_priority
  ,s.id as service_id
from customer_services cs
left join service s 
    on ','||preferred_service||',' not like '%,' || s.service_name || ',%' 
)
select  customer_id
  ,min(preferred_service)as  preferred_service
  ,listagg(service_name,',') next_best_offer
  ,listagg(service_id,',') next_best_offer_ids
  ,min(minNext_offer_priority) minNext_offer_priority
from cte1
where priority=minNext_offer_priority
group by customer_id
```

Example of output

| CUSTOMER_ID | PREFERRED_SERVICE | NEXT_BEST_OFFER | NEXT_BEST_OFFER_IDS | MINNEXT_OFFER_PRIORITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaaa | P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET | BILL_PAY,MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET | 1,3 | 1 |
| bbbb | P2P_TRANSFER_OFFNET,BILL_PAY | MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET,P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET | 3,5 | 1 |
| cccc | P2P_TRANSFER_OFFNET | BILL_PAY,MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET,P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET | 1,3,5 | 1 |
| dddd | MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET | BILL_PAY,P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET | 1,5 | 1 |
| eeee | MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET,P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET | BILL_PAY | 1 | 1 |
| ffff | BILL_PAY | MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET,P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET | 3,5 | 1 |
| gggg | P2P_TRANSFER_OFFNET,BILL_PAY | MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET,P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET | 3,5 | 1 |
| hhhh | MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET,P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET, GOVT_PAY | BILL_PAY | 1 | 1 |
| iiii | MERCHANT_PAY_ONNET,P2P_TRANSFER_ONNET, BILL_PAY | P2P_TRANSFER_OFFNET | 4 | 2 |

Comment: I think this could be a solution but to a different challenge, Thanks though, My main Challenge is, there is no priority in my dataset, and the arrangement of the preferred service does not matter while determining the next best offer: as I elucidate, if a customer prefers product (XXXX,YYYY) is the same as ('YYYY,XXXX')

Comment: I did not write about the order of services. Services are considered as sets. ``Set`` {XXXX,YYYY} is equivalent to {YYYY,XXXX}. Priority is about what next service - which next service should be taken.

Comment: This is great approach, but it doesnt solve the challenge, because assume that the next best offers are not in order of importance, its more likely of ‘if statement’ it is defined from business rule